# Linked List in c or c++

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

I am trying to do intersect two linked list but i got some problem when i compare two data of two list using `<` or `>`.

```
 if(t2->data < t1->data)
    t2 = t2->next;  
    if(t2->data > t1->data)
    t1 = t1->next;
```

The code stop executing. But when I comment those code it works and give output

```
struct node *getIntersection (struct node *head1, struct node *head2)
    {
        struct node *result = NULL;
        struct node *t1 = head1;
        struct node *t2 = head1;

        while (t1 != NULL && t2 != NULL)
        {
            if (t2->data==t1->data){
                push (&result, t1->data);
                t1=t1->next;
                t2=t2->next;

            }
            if(t2->data < t1->data)
            t2 = t2->next;  
            if(t2->data > t1->data)
            t1 = t1->next;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Check `t2->next != NULL` before 2nd if.

Comment: Hmm got it. thank you :)

Comment: And you intended to set both `t1` and `t2` to point into the same list?

Answer (score 2):

Here try this:

```
 struct node *getIntersection (struct node *head1, struct node *head2)
 {
    struct node *result = NULL;
    struct node *t1 = head1;
    struct node *t2 = head1;

    while (t1 != NULL && t2 != NULL)
    {
        if (t2->data==t1->data){
            push (&result, t1->data);
            t1=t1->next;
            t2=t2->next;

        }
        if(t1 != NULL && t2 != NULL){
        if(t2->data < t1->data)
        t2 = t2->next;  }

        if(t2 !=NULL){
        if(t2->data > t1->data)
        t1 = t1->next;}
    }

    return result;
}
```

I guess the problem is that you're not verifying the next t1 or t2, and if it's NULL , It's normal that the program will stop executing